# Why does my Resistance popup show two percentages?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I hover over an individual Resistance in character details, it shows two percentages added together:

[image: Cropped screenshot showing Cold Resistance tooltip]

Granted, they should be multiplied, not added, as I am obviously not invincible, but where does this other number come from? It is the same for all elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second number is damage reduction from your items or skills. In my case, it was the Unhallowed Essence set, that gives 60% damage reduction.

Despite strange way to display two numbers added together, second number is calculated in a correct mutiplicative way if there are several skills or items in play. For example, adding a Cindercoat (50% damage reduction) changes my displayed number from 59.96% to 79.98%